# Usage of “was” instead of “had” before another action

Tags: past-perfect

I’m learning the Unit from “English Grammar in use” and there is a sentence:

> The building that was destroyed in the fire has now been rebuilt.

Could you please explain why we shouldn’t use **had been destroyed** for example? It seems that it was destroyed before it has been rebuilt .
Can’t understand :)
thanks

Comment: Can you edit to clarify why you think _had been destroyed_ is wrong?

Comment: I’m not sure, it’s wrong. Do you mean both variants are correct? I didn’t think about that...

Comment: The past perfect is used for an event in the past that happened before another event in the past.  But what are the two events in the past?  **Destroyed** is in the past, but **has been rebuilt** is actually a present tense construction!

Comment: @stangdon Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The past perfect can be used for an action which began before the time of speaking in the past, and was still continuing at that time or stopped at that time or just before it.The simple past is used when the action took place at a definite time even though this time is not mentioned, eg. I bought this car in Karachi."That was destroyed in the past" is a non defining relative clause which gives more information about the building.So, "was destroyed is correct". "Had been" seems  incorrect to me.